# How to solve problem about [Errno 11] unable to lock file?

Tags: h5py, ioerror

I want to run solo (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cels.2020.05.010.) to detect doublets in the scRNAseq dataset, but when I run this, it jumps a BlockIOError to me, like the picture.

[image: enter image description here.]

I googled this problem and tried upgrading h5py, numpy and ipython, but it doesn't work. I also tried modifying the ~/.bashrc, but it can't execute because my server is public and it doesn't support this. The reboot didn't seem to work either. What can I do to solve this? QAQ

Comment: Because the level is not enough, the image can only be placed in the link。

Comment: Hey my problem has already solved:-)  I created a ./ child process on the command line running the bash script which caused a process conflict. I think the reason for the IO error is probably because of the socket conflict caused by the creation of extra child processes.